# struts2 confirm box with action

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, struts2

I am trying to call struts2 action when I click 'OK' in confirm box. I have an id from jsp and I want to pass it into the action. I've tried several ways with no success.

One thing is using href:

```
 <s:url action="disable" var="urlTag">
     <s:param name="id"><s:property value="id"/></s:param>
 </s:url>

window.location.href="{urlTag}";
```

I also tried using ajax

```
        $.ajax( {  
            type: "POST",        
            url: "%{urlTag}",  //will this declaration of action work?   
            dataType: "json",  
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
            data: "",  
            success: function() {  
                alert("success");    
            }  
       });
```

I am new to this and really want to get though it. Thank you for any help!

Comment: No, it won't work, because OGNL expressions are evaluated only in struts tags' attributes. But you might try JSP EL.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it as following.

```
 <s:url id="yourActionId" action="yourAction">
    <s:param name="param1" value="param1Value"/>
    <s:param name="param2" value="param2Value"/>
 </s:url> 
 <s:a href="%{yourActionId}" onclick = "return confirmBox();"><b>Save</b></s:a>
```

& your javascript function should be as follows.

```
function confirmBox() {
   var answer;
   answer = window.confirm("Do you really want to perform this action");
   if (answer == true) {
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}
```

What we have done here is, In s:url tag we have given action to perform with the parameters & given an id to it. That id is passed to the s:a tag & on click of s:a link we are calling a java script function which will open a confirm box & return true if you press OK & action will be called. If you press cancel it will return false & action will not be called. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Pravin, however, I need to have a button not a link.

Comment: You can use <s:form> & <s:submit> for that & if you dont want to take any input from user, pass your parameter value in <s:hidden> tag & call an above confirmBox() method on onsubmit of a <s:form> or on onclick of <s:submit>.

Comment: Thanks Pravin, I got my code work by another way, i.e passing the new values after click OK to the jsp (using hidden field) and use another button to call the action.

Answer (score 0):

To make your code work with Struts tags:

```javascript
window.location.href = "<s:property value='%{#urlTag}' />";
```

and

```javascript
$.ajax( {  
       type: "POST",        
        url: "<s:property value='%{#urlTag}' />",
```

That said, I'm not saying this is what you need. Are you sure about what you need to do ? GET ? POST ? An AJAX call, what ?

Comment: thanks, I think I dont need to use ajax. I just need to call an action and pass the id to the action.